# Function that returns the index of the first parameter in the array passed as the second parameter

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am a begginer in Python and I can't find a way to write a function that returns the index of the first parameter in the array passed as the second parameter. I have tried this, but i doesn't work:

```
def find_index(element, array):
    for i in array:
        if i == element:
            return i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.index()` method.
This will do:

```
def find_index(element, array):
    return array.index(element)
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If you think this is the solution to your problem, please mark it with the green checkmark so that people with the same problem can find the answer quickly

Answer (score 2):

`i` is not the index, it's the element. You can use `enumerate()` to get the indexes as well

```
for i, val in enumerate(array):
    if val == element:
        return i
```

Answer (score 0):

you compare counter of the loop with your elemnt 1by1. i edited your code. i hope it works

```
def find_index(element, array):
for i in array:
    if array[i] == element:
        return i
```